# Center-aligning a div inside a div, and a div inside a div inside a div

Tags: html, center, vertical-alignment, alignment

I am having troubles aligning one of my divs in the center (horizontally), and another one of my divs in the center (vertically).

The Horizontal div, is the the wrapper for the middle section of the website (the buttons).

The vertical div is the wrapper for the "Eller" in between the buttons.

[Http://wwww.vilduhelst.dk](http://vilduhelst.dk)

I have already tried using the
"Margin: 0px auto;" property, without any result at all.

This is my CSS code:

```
body{
background: url(media/pattern.png);
}

.headerdiv{
text-align:center;
margin-top:50px;
width:223px;
height:121px;
background: url(media/logo.png) no-repeat bottom;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

}

.topbardiv{
padding-top:60px;
text-align:center;
background: url(media/HeaderDepression_shadow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

 #buttons{
margin-top:100px;
width:100%;
height:227px;
text-align:center;

}



.buttonscontent{
width:90%;
margin: 0px auto;
}

.reddiv{
float:left;
display:inline;
background: url(media/RedButtonShadow.png) no-repeat bottom;

}

.redbutton{
background: url(media/RedButton.png) no-repeat bottom;
width:387px;
height:227px;
border:none;
display:inline;
margin-bottom:25px;
}


.redbutton:hover{
background: url(media/RedButtonHover.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

.redbutton:active{
background: url(media/RedButtonOnclick.png) no-repeat bottom;
}


.textdiv{
text-align:center;
float:left;
padding-left:30px;
padding-right:30px;
height:200px;
}

.textdivcontent{
background: url(media/Eller.png) no-repeat;
height:95px;
width:129px;

}

.bluediv{
display:inline;
float:left;
background: url(media/RedButtonShadow.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

.bluebutton{
background: url(media/BlueButton.png) no-repeat bottom;
width:387px;
height:227px;
border:none;
display:inline;
margin-bottom:25px;

}

.bluebutton:hover{
background: url(media/BlueButtonHover.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

.bluebutton:active{
background: url(media/BlueButtonOnclick.png) no-repeat bottom;
}


.footerseperation{
padding-top:175px;
text-align:center;
background: url(media/FooterSeperation.png) no-repeat bottom;
}

.copyright{
background: url(media/copyright.png) no-repeat bottom;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:205px;
height:24px;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title> Hvad vil du helst? - Dilemma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div class="headerdiv">

    </div>

    <div class="topbardiv">

    </div>

        <div id="buttons">

            <div class="buttonscontent">

                <div class="reddiv">
                    <input type="button" class="redbutton" />
                </div>

                <div class="textdiv">
                    <div class="textdivcontent">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bluediv">
                    <input type="button" class="bluebutton" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="footerseperation">

        </div>

        <div class="copyright">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To generate a horizontal center effect, set display: inline-block;text-align:left; for the inner div and text-align:center; for the outer div.

Comment: Tried, didn't change anything :/

Comment: did you ensure the container div has display:block; and is big enough?

Comment: The container div does indeed have display:block, you can see the width of the divs in my code. Container = #Buttons, Inner div = .buttonscontent

Comment: I was wrong, the div is actually centered. It is the content of the div which is not. How do i center that?